# How to change app settings of Web.Config using targets.wpp

Tags: c#, azure, msbuild, web-config, msbuild-wpp

I have created a wpp.targets file which does all the deployment in azure. I want to change the appsetting property of webconfig during deployment to azure. I found a sample in http://sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,25ddd39e-59de-4e35-becc-de19dcc5e4ea.aspx , which uses the pubxml and parameters.xml. I want to use wpp.targets instead of pubxml.

```
  <appSettings>
    <!-- TODO: set this in the azure config -->
    <add key="customer" value="xyz" />
  </appSettings>
```

Need to update the customer value to "client" during deployment and web.config file should reflect the changes in the deployed folder like below

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="customer" value="client" />
  </appSettings>
```

**ANSWER**

I have achieved using the **ProjectParametersXMLFile** in msDeploy

```
msbuild Api.csproj    /p:ProjectParametersXMLFile="c:\parameter.xml"/p:PublishSettingsFile=%publishFileLocation%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parameter xml file

for example

```
<parameters >
  <parameter name="customer" description="web Job queue name"  defaultValue="sitetest1">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" 
                    scope="\\web.config$" 
                    match="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='customer']/@value" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter name="customer" description="web Job queue name"  defaultValue="sitetest">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile"
                    scope="\\app.config$"
                    match="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='customer']/@value" />
  </parameter>
</parameters>
```

this file will change the appsettings when you deploy in azure based on default value you provide